# Cannot open a plist file in Objective C that was generated in PHP using CFPropertyList

Tags: php, objective-c, plist, nskeyedunarchiver

I have a binary file that contains a serialised plist. The file was generated in PHP by the statements:

```
namespace CFPropertyList;

require_once(__DIR__.'/../classes/CFPropertyList/CFPropertyList.php');

$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));

$plist_filename = __DIR__ . '/simple_array.plist';

$plist = new CFPropertyList();
$td = new \CFPropertyList\CFTypeDetector();
$guessedStructure = $td->toCFType($a);
$plist->add($guessedStructure);
$plist->saveBinary($plist_filename);
```

Binary contents of simple_array.plist file are:

> 6270 6c69 7374 3030 d301 0203 0405 0651 6151 6251 6355 6170 706c 6556
>   6261 6e61 6e61 a307 0809 5178 5179 517a 080f 1113 151b 2226 282a 0000
>   0000 0000 0101 0000 0000 0000 000a 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
>   002c

I can open simple_array.plist in Xcode (by double clicking on it) without a problem.

I can also re-open it later in PHP using the following statements also without a problem:

```
$plist = new CFPropertyList( $plist_filename, CFPropertyList::FORMAT_BINARY );
```

The problem is when I try to open the file in Objective C. These are the statements I am using:

```
NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path_to_plist_file];
NSArray *fileInfoArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tempData];
```

`fileInfoArray` is `nil`!

These last two statements open other plist files that were generated in Objective C but not the file generated by PHP (on Linux).

Any idea what is going on here? This webpage http://nshipster.com/nscoding/ talks about the importance of NSCoding for NSKeyed​Archiver... could that be relevant and if so how do I apply in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the plist into a dictionary with:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
```

Or you can use `NSPropertyListSerialization`:

```
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:0 format:&format error:&error];
```

And with your data, both of those worked for me.

For more information, see the [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Rob. It solved my problem. It also explains why reading the plist into an array didn't work: its structure is too complex. (The real plist I am dealing with is hugely complex) . Thanks for your time.